# Excel VBA .find matches when there is no match

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to find if a value in a cell matches the list of values in a named range that defines the dropdown for the cell.

My problem is if the user enters an asterik in the cell, this value is not a valid dropdown value but it validates to the first item in the list.  In the code below, if szCellValue = "*" then the validation does not work.

Does anyone know how to get this search to work?

**Range Values**

DESK

ON-SITE

N/A

**Code to determine the match**

```
Dim bError As Boolean

Dim oCell As Range
Dim oFoundCell As Range

Dim szCellValue As String
Dim szLookupValue As String

szCellValue = CStr(Trim(oCell.Value2))

' Validate In Dropdown if Length > 0
If Len(szCellValue) > 0 Then
    ' See if the oCell value in the oRange loop exists in this szValidationNamedRange dropdown
    Set oFoundCell = GetRangeFromNamedRange(cValidateCellData.ValidationNamedRange).Find(szCellValue, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)

    ' If Value Not Found in Dropdown...or if they've typed in an id value (which will be found on odd numbered columns)
    If oFoundCell Is Nothing Then
        Call SetError(oCell.Text, cValidateCellData, "Not a Valid Value for drop down " + cValidateCellData.ValidationNamedRange + ".")
        bError = True
    End If

Else
    If cValidateCellData.Required Then
        Call SetError(oCell.Text, cValidateCellData, "Please input a value. This is a Required Field.")
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Just a question, why are you validating by code if the typed value is in the range since you already have a data validation list??

Comment: You can use `~` to escape the asterisk. Eg:  `szCellValue = Replace(szCellValue, "*", "~*")`

Comment: @TimWilliams I think you should post it as an answer, it  answers the question precisely and is useful isn't it?

Comment: @A.S.H - done!  Was on my phone, so it was easier to comment...

Comment: Well done @TimWilliams.

Comment: I am validating to make sure that the value is in the list.  The ~ does not actually work. It is still doing a wildcared

Answer (score 1):

You can use ~ to escape the asterisk.

Eg:

```
Dim bError As Boolean

Dim oCell As Range
Dim oFoundCell As Range

Dim szCellValue As String
Dim szLookupValue As String

szCellValue = CStr(Trim(oCell.Value2))

' Validate In Dropdown if Length > 0
If Len(szCellValue) > 0 Then
    ' See if the oCell value in the oRange loop exists in this szValidationNamedRange dropdown
    '  (escape * using ~)
    Set oFoundCell = GetRangeFromNamedRange(cValidateCellData.ValidationNamedRange) _
          .Find(Replace(szCellValue, "*", "~*"), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)

    ' If Value Not Found in Dropdown...or if they've typed in an id value
    '    (which will be found on odd numbered columns)
    If oFoundCell Is Nothing Then
        Call SetError(oCell.Text, cValidateCellData, _
            "Not a Valid Value for drop down " & cValidateCellData.ValidationNamedRange & ".")
        bError = True
    End If

Else
    If cValidateCellData.Required Then
        Call SetError(oCell.Text, cValidateCellData, _
              "Please input a value. This is a Required Field.")
    End If
End If
```

Comment: I did this fix, but it does not work.  oFoundCell still is finding the very first item in the list

Comment: The Find part worked for me in testing, but I can't replicate your entire setup...

Comment: I have a lookup tab used to define ranges and a user tab where the user enters data. I set every cell in a column to be a data validation of type list. Excel does not prevent the user from typing or pasting into a cell so I am attempting to validate the cell value exists in the list as an item. Unfortunately, if the value is * or ~, oFoundCell points to the first entry in the list

Comment: If I have "One, Two, Three" in A1:A3 then `? Range("A1:A3").Find("~*") Is Nothing` return `True`.  I can't say why you're getting different results.